# Add Item To html Combobox Server Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

How Can I (Or Is It Possible?) Add Item to Html Combobox ServerSide ?
Or Bind It in behind Code in asp.net ?
Does My question Clear?

Comment: does it have to be a html combobox? if not, why not create an ASP.NET ComboBox (which doesn't exist off the shelf, but you can easily extend an existing control - plenty of examples around on the net). I think the ACT has a ComboBox control you could use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948024/bind-asp-net-server-side-data-to-html-combobox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to modify a HTML `select` tag in code behind?

If yes, here is what you need to do:

1. Add `runat=server` in your tag
   (`<select id="s1" runat="server">`)
2. To bind the control server side, use
   a datasource (a datatable for
   example), set the datasource `s1.DataSource = dt` set the property
   `s1.DataTextField` to the property of
   the datasource you want to bind as
   the text shown to the user, the
   `s1.ValueTextField` to the property of
   the datasource to use as the value,
   and call the `s1.Databind()` method
3. To add/remove items (options) you
   can call
   `s1.Items.Add/AddRange/Insert/Remove/RemoveAt`
   method.

Comment: No i cant add runatserver to my tag because i want to use it with jquery autocomplete http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948024/bind-asp-net-server-side-data-to-html-combobox

Comment: @shaahin: I don't understand, could be more explicit? What is the matter with jquery autocomplete? How exactly do you want databinding to work? Request data from server via jQuery?